# Rigidbody.Moveposition issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a type of projectile with Rigidbody:

```cs
private void FiredAsProjectile(GameObject target)
{
    Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.Zero;
    float velMod = 8f // A placeholder value to later calculate with mass / velocity

    if(target != null)
    {
        moveVector = (target.transform.position - transform.position);
        m_rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveVector * Time.deltaTime * velMod);
    }
}
```

This is updated via FixedUpdate upon calling this method somewhere else. I have a few things I needed this to behave: to have velocity output and move to a position, not direction.

However, I'm getting a weird outcome. Even though this object moves as a kinematic rigidbody and its interpolation is set to None this object slows down before reaching the target vector as if it has interpolation. Let's say I wanted a bullet to be fired from the barrel and fly to a point in world instead of direction, that's what I wanted this object to behave like, but not quite so.

Am I missing something or misunderstanding something? 
Is there a better way to move this kinematic rigidbody whilst still outputting rigidbody.velocity and still collide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you don't `Normalize` the `moveVector`.

To explain why this happens, we'll suppose that `Time.deltaTime = 0.01` every step:

- At `t0` time, let's say that the distance between the moving object (in x = 0) and the target object (x = 100) is 100.
- The argument of `MovePosition` is `0 + 100*8*.01 = 8` and the object is moved accordingly to this new position (since you said it's Kinematic without interpolation)
- At `t1` time, `moveVector = 100-8 = 92`
- The new argument now is `8 + 92*8*.01 = 15.36`

Notice that between `t0` and `t1` you moved 8 units, whereas between `t1` and `t2` you moved only 7.36 units. So, the more your moving object is near the target object, the less you'll move the object, giving the effect of "slowing down" (and moreover it'll never reach the target object, you'll stop at a distance equal to the minimum floating number precision).

In order to fix this, you just need to normalize the `moveVector`, i.e. making its module fixed every step. So, just add this line:

```cs
moveVector = (target.transform.position - transform.position);
moveVector.Normalize();
m_rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveVector * Time.deltaTime * velMod);
```

and the distance moved every step will always be the same regardless of distance.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! especially for the explanation! Your answer to me was multiple lessons via one answer! However, I still have more to ask about this object's movement. The velocity is fixed now, but it stops before reaching its destination. (there was no collision) and then keeps trying to reach it and stops every time where it's stopping.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow: do you mean that when the moving object has reached the target object it starts to "flicker" around the position of the target object?

Comment: I understand this would be better if shown, I'm sorry. Let's say objA is projectile and objB is the goal. objA flies in straight line with behaviour with constant velocity. When objA reaches about 90% of its flight path it acts as if it has reached the destination and starts falling(which I'm okay if there was collision, but there is not). and when it gains distance from objB, objA tries to do the same over and over.

Comment: I think I understood. So this means that you have some other code that, at some point, disables `isKinematic` on objA allowing the gravity to start working on it?

Comment: Precisely. That's the missing part of the puzzle I've not mentioned. I'm intending this rigidbody object to change its states in case scenarios. The projectile flight behaviour should connect to free-floating object 'at collision'(via OnCollisionEnter()), but I was puzzled when this was happening mid-air where the objA of mentioned have not collided with anything.

Comment: Now that you have solved the moving problem, it's better if you open a new question with all the code and information regarding this second problem you mentioned.

Comment: Okay, I'd like to dig in for just a bit and come back for new question opening if I get stuck again, though. Thanks for the lesson!